# flask include template with variable

Tags: templates, flask, include

Just curious why this is working, since haven't found such examples in flask and jinjia2 official docs. It seems `include` is just simply put the content to the place just as it is, right?

```py
# app.py
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    names = ['John', 'James', 'Jenny']
    return render_template('index.html', names=names)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5200)
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    Welcome!

    <!-- I know this is working as official docs -->
    {% for name in names %}
        <div class='card'>Welcome {{ name }}!</div>
    {% endfor %}

    <!-- but haven't found any examples like below, but it works -->
    {% for name in names %}
        {% include "card.html" %}
    {% endfor %}
    
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!-- card.html -->
<div class='card'>Welcome {{ name }}!</div>
```

[code example in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdhkP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/

> Include
>
> The include tag is useful to include a template and return the
> rendered contents of that file into the current namespace:
>
> {% include 'header.html' %}
> Body {% include 'footer.html' %}
>
> Included templates have access to the variables of the active context
> by default.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer! "Included templates have **access to the variables** of the active context by default." this is what I want to know!

Answer (score 0):

This code will work because cards.html will be reloaded at each step of the "for" loop.

We can include a template in another template in the jinja structure. We don't have to use "for" when doing this.

The list elements to be navigated in the "for" loop are rendered from the flask view. In this way, we can use the rendered list and its elements as we want in the specified template while rendering.

```
    {% for name in names %}
        {% include "card.html" %}
    {% endfor %}
```